# Creating set from text file using generics in java

Tags: java, set

I am trying to create a set which reads from a text file. This is what I have so far and all it returns is an empty set. For example, if the text file contains 1,2,3 (each on a seperate line with no commas) then the function should return a set containing 1,2,3. The set implementation also uses generics.

```
public MySet<T> createMySet(String name) throws MySetException {
    MySet<T> result = MySetFactory.getInstance().getMySet();
    String filename = name + ".txt";
    try {
      File MySetFile = new File(filename);
      if (MySetFile.exists()){
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line = bufReader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
          T value = (T) line;
          result.add(value);
          line = bufReader.readLine();
        }
        bufReader.close();
      }

    }

    catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: How is generics relevant?

Comment: Why are you casting a string into a T? My suggestion is to write the project without generics, then (if you need to for the assignment) add them back into the working project.